# Go word-by-word through a text file and replace certain words

Tags: c++

My intended program is simple: Take each word of a text file and replace it with asterisks if it's a swear word. For instance, if the text file was "Hello world, bitch" then it would be modified to "Hello world, ***********".

I have the tool for taking a word as a string and replacing it with asterisks if needed. I need help setting up the main part of my program because I get confused with all the fstream stuff. Should I instead make a new file with the replaced words and then overwrite the previous file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

const char* BANNED_WORDS[] = {"fuck", "shit", "bitch", "ass", "damn"};

void filter_word(std::string&);
void to_lower_case(std::string&);

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {

    return 0;
}

void filter_word(std::string& word) { 
    std::string wordCopy = word;
    to_lower_case(wordCopy);
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(BANNED_WORDS)/sizeof(const char*); ++k) 
        if (wordCopy == BANNED_WORDS[k]) 
            word.replace(word.begin(), word.end(), word.size(), '*');
}

void to_lower_case(std::string& word) { 
    for (std::string::iterator it = word.begin(); it != word.end(); ++it) { 
        switch (*it) { 
            case 'A': *it = 'a';
            case 'B': *it = 'b';
            case 'C': *it = 'c';
            case 'D': *it = 'd';
            case 'E': *it = 'e';
            case 'F': *it = 'f';
            case 'G': *it = 'g';
            case 'H': *it = 'h';
            case 'I': *it = 'i';
            case 'J': *it = 'j';
            case 'K': *it = 'k';
            case 'L': *it = 'l';
            case 'M': *it = 'm';
            case 'N': *it = 'n';
            case 'O': *it = 'o';
            case 'P': *it = 'p';
            case 'Q': *it = 'q';
            case 'R': *it = 'r';
            case 'S': *it = 's';
            case 'T': *it = 't';
            case 'U': *it = 'u';
            case 'V': *it = 'v';
            case 'W': *it = 'w';
            case 'X': *it = 'x';
            case 'Y': *it = 'y';
            case 'Z': *it = 'z';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Borgleader: Citation needed.

Comment: Swap your switch statement in `to_lower_case` for:`#include <ctype.h>
*it = tolower(*it);`

Comment: I think For your problem you have to create new file with replaced Words and Replace previous file by new one.

Comment: Also, for tolower, the lack of break statements means the last case will always be executed, so it does not perform the thing you want at all, see http://ideone.com/LRd3wk for a demo :)

Comment: @Borgleader: Only if you can show why ASCII tables would be relevant to the question. Otherwise, I'd prefer a Standard reference.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's been pointed out to me that [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) is probably what you're referring to. I guess I should've prefaced my comment with a disclaimer saying this will only work IFF the system uses ascii encoding. In my defense, that is the case for all the systems I've come across.

Comment: @Borgleader: And me, I've only ever come across systems where people don't swear, so I have a very efficient answer to the question. Shall I post it? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I see where you're going. Question though, if you know your system is using ASCII as an encoding and if you know this code will only run on a system using ASCII encoding. Why not take advantage of that fact and simplify the code? (PS: I removed the suggestion, I'm just asking out of curiosity)

Comment: @Borgleader Except that it isn't.

Comment: @Borgleader With regards to ASCII, I don't know of any modern system which uses it.

Comment: @JamesKanze Do you mind dropping in to Lounge<C++>? This comment section is getting mighty long.

Comment: @Borgleader: By all means, you should have architecture-specific implmentations if those afford you benefits. But those should be clearly labeled as such and factored in a way that makes for easy porting. More relevantly, if you want to case-modify modern Unicode text, you'll need a better solution anyway, and that's probably something people *will* be demanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution to modifying a file is to generate a new
file, then delete the old and rename the new.  In your case,
because your replacement text has exactly the same length as
your new text, you can do it in place, with something like:

```
std::fstream file( fileName, ios_base::in | ios_base::out );
if ( !file.is_open() ) {
    //  put error handling here...

std::string word;
std::fstream::pos_type startOfWord;
while ( file.peek() != std::fstream::traits::eof() ) {
    if ( ::isalpha( file.peek() ) ) {
        if ( word.empty() ) {
            startOfWord = file.tellg();
        }
        word += file.get();
    } else {
        if ( !word.empty() ) {
            if ( std::find_if( banned.begin(), banned.end(), CaseInsensitiveCompare() ) ) {
                file.seekp( startOfWord );
                file.write( std::string( word.size(), '*').c_str(), word.size() );
            }
            word.clear();
        }
        file.get();
    }
}
```

with:

```
struct CaseInsensitiveCompare
{
    bool operator()( unsigned char lhs, unsigned char rhs ) const
    {
        return ::tolower( lhs ) == ::tolower( rhs );
    }

    bool operator()( std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs ) const
    {
        return lhs.size() == rhs.size()
            && std::equal( lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), *this )
    }
};
```

The `tellg` and `seekp` probably aren't the most efficient
operations around, but if the file is large, and you don't have
to seek too often, it may still be more efficient than writing
a completely new file.  Of course, if efficiency is an issue,
you might want to consider `mmap`, and doing the job directly in
memory.  That would certainly be the most efficient, and
probably the easiest to code as well.  But it would be platform
dependent, and would require extra effort to handle files larger
than your available address space.

Also, for the future (since there is a standard `tolower` that
you can use), when doing code translation (which is really what
`to_lower_case` does), use a table.  It's much simpler and
faster:

```
char
to_lower_case( char ch )
{
    char translationTable[] =
    {
        //  ...
    };
    return translationTable[static_cast<unsigned char>( ch )];
}
```

If you don't want your code to be dependent on the encoding, you
can use dynamic initialization:

```
if ( !initialized ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; ++ i ) {
        translationTable[i] = i;
    }
    static char const from[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    static char const to[]   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for ( int i = 0; i != sizeof(from); ++ i ) {
        translationTable[from[i]] = to[i];
    }
}
```

This is *not* a good idea for things like `tolower`, however;
you would have to know all of the possible upper case
characters, which in turn depends on the encoding.  (The
functions in `<ctype.h>` do do something like this.  And
redefine the translation table each time you change locale.)  It
can be useful for other types of mappings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a code to read file word by word and replace if the word is one of `BANNED_WORDS`
So here is a solution for `main()`:

```
     int main()
        {
          std::vector <std::string> words; // Vector to hold our words we read in.
          std::string str; // Temp string to
          std::cout << "Read from a file!" << std::endl;       

          std::ifstream fin("thisfile.txt"); // Open it up!
          while (fin >> str) // Will read up to eof() and stop at every
          {                  // whitespace it hits. (like spaces!)
            words.push_back(str);
          }
          fin.close(); // Close that file!

          std::ofstream fout("temp.txt"); // open temp file 

          for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
          {                                 // replace all words and add it to temp file
             filter_word(words.at(i));
             fout<<words.at(i) << endl;
          }

           // Add code for replace the file       
          return 0;
        }
```

And for `to_lower_case()` you can use

```
#include <ctype.h>
// ...
    *it = tolower(*it);
```

As suggested by [**Paul Evans**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21329520/3110262)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Reading word by word as above will loose white space (which may be important).  It will also cause the banned word to be missed if it is adjacent to any punctuation: put an ! after the word, and it passes.

Comment: And of course, `*it = tolower(*it);` is undefined behavior (at least if plain `char` is signed, as it often is).